# Ansible parsing issues when running fabric command

Tags: yaml, ansible

I'm trying to run the following fabric command from ansible on the local machine:

```
- name: Deploy api using fabric
  command: fab -R {{ fabric_deploy_env }} deploy:{{ fabric_deploy_app }},revision={{ fabric_deploy_revision }},restart={{ fabric_deploy_restart }}
    args:
      chdir: "{{ fabric_deploy_path }}"
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  when: fabric_deploy
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script, /var/lib/jenkins/infrastructure/provision/roles/rails/tasks/main.yml
Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 42, column 9

  command: fab -R {{ fabric_deploy_env }} deploy:{{ fabric_deploy_app }},revision={{ fabric_deploy_revision }},restart={{ fabric_deploy_restart }}
    args:
        ^
```

I've tried numerous ways to address this issue but nothing seems to work. I believe the = symbol in the fabric command is causing issues with the ansible parser but can't seem to figure out a work around.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem simply is indention. A YAML key can only hold a scalar OR an associative array.

Your definition though tries to do both, `command` having the executable command as a string assigned but also having the property `args`.

```
  command: fab -R {{ fabric_deploy_env }} deploy:{{ fabric_deploy_app }},revision={{ fabric_deploy_revision }},restart={{ fabric_deploy_restart }}
    args:
      chdir: "{{ fabric_deploy_path }}"
```

`args` has to be on the same level as `command`.

```
  command: fab -R {{ fabric_deploy_env }} deploy:{{ fabric_deploy_app }},revision={{ fabric_deploy_revision }},restart={{ fabric_deploy_restart }}
  args:
    chdir: "{{ fabric_deploy_path }}"
```